# Not understanding correlation names on sql joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, join, sql-server-2012

Can someone explaing to me how to correlate these names on this join? When I execute I get the errors saying The Objects in the From clause have the same exposed names

```
select
inv_mast.item_id as Item,
inv_loc.location_id as location,
company.company_name as company,
vendor_supplier.vendor_id as vendorID
from
inv_loc
join inv_mast on inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = inv_loc.inv_mast_uid 
join inv_loc on company.company_id = inv_loc.company_id 
JOIN company ON (company.company_id = vendor_supplier.company_id)
```

Comment: you are using the `inv_loc` in the `from` and a `join`, but you are not giving them any aliases, so when you say: `inv_loc.company_id` SQL Server doesn't know which one you want

Comment: why are you joining 2 times the inv_loc table? yo can join 1 time with 2 conditions

Answer (score 1):

You join to `inv_loc` twice - you either need to fix your joins, or introduce an alias, so something like:

```
select      inv_mast.item_id as Item,
            mast.location_id as MasterLocation,
            companylocation.location_id as CompanyLocation,
            company.company_name as company,
            vendor_supplier.vendor_id as vendorID

from        inv_loc AS mast

join        inv_mast 
    on      inv_mast.inv_mast_uid = mast.inv_mast_uid 

join        inv_loc AS companylocation
    on      company.company_id = companylocation.company_id 

JOIN        company 
    ON      company.company_id = vendor_supplier.company_id
```